# Visual Studio 2010 WPF Project ran in debug or release will not allow drag and drop to any control

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, wpf-controls, expression-blend-4

I had started a question here: [WPF drag and drop files onto TreeView from windows explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476465/wpf-drag-and-drop-files-onto-treeview-from-windows-explorer) but I just discovered this is a **totally different problem** that what I thought it was.

I have an extremely simple test case.

I was using a treeview but if I use a simple **listbox** with no code just the following xaml

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <ListBox Height="312" Background="#FFBDD6FF" AllowDrop="True"/>
</StackPanel>
```

If I run the project in **expression blend** and drag a file over the listbox I see the **arrow and the little square below it** that incdicates you can drag and drop.

If I run the same project in **visual studio** and drag a file over the listbox I get a **black circle** with a line through it.

What could be wrong with my computer or code that is causing that?

Comment: I just tested your code exactly on my computer and I get the square in Visual Studio.   I would apply all services packs and patches and reboot.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Is it possible that you are running Visual Studio as Administrator and Expression Blend normally?

Comment: Yes.  Does running as administrator interfere with drag and drop?

Comment: Yes it does, try starting a notepad.exe instance and drag&drop a file from explorer. See that it will open. Now try the same with an instance started as administrator, which will not open the file

Comment: That explains all my problems for the last day and a half then.  I also found this bug submission on Microsoft Connect: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/537964/drag-and-drop-to-open-file-is-not-working-at-all.  I guess if notepad has the same behaivior it isn't really a bug.  Some kind of security thing I suppose?

Comment: No this is not a bug, elevated (in your case VisualStudio) and non-elevated (in your case Explorer) processes are shielded from direct communication with each other. Welcome to the wonderfull world uf UAC

Comment: It is called UIPI, take the first google hit.  You can't hijack the privileges of an elevated program with D+D.  Makes sense, no workaround.  And not a real problem to your user.