# Why my WPF application has Drag & Drop disabled (even when AllowDrop is true)?

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

My WPF application inhibits the Drop of files from Windows Explorer, showing a Stop-sign cursor.

I've tried setting the AllowDrop property (that of the UIElement ancestor) to true on the main window and contained controls, but no luck at all, no drag-drop events are fired.

Any ideas or suggestions to find the cause?

Comment: Can you provide some code to show your implementation ?

Comment: I cannot provide code because it's huge (a lot of custom wpf controls). I need some point of view or cue from which to face this problem, from where to start looking for the solution.

Comment: what trust level is your app?

Comment: @GarryVass my App has the default trust level of a WPF desktop application. It is not an XBAP application for web deployment, so it has full trust I believe.

Answer (score 26):

Solved!

The problem was that executing my app thru VisualStudio (run/debug) prevented the interop with Windows' drag & drop mechanism. Running the App as stand-alone makes it work, but cannot debug interactively.

This answer helped a lot:
[Visual Studio 2010 WPF Project ran in debug or relase will not allow drag and drop to any control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485909/visual-studio-2010-wpf-project-ran-in-debug-or-relase-will-not-allow-drag-and-dr)

Comment: At least it's possible to attach to the process, and hit breakpoints afterward.

Answer (score 20):

In my case it was running Visual Studio as Administrator on Windows 10. The UAC prevented the drag/drop. When I ran VS without elevating drag/drop started working in debug mode.

Comment: stambikk, you just saved me hours!

Comment: This is really strange behavior but you're right.  Thanks for finding this.

Comment: It's because the user running your application in Debug mode is a different user than the one who opened the Windows Explorer window. Same reason your debug version of an application won't see networked drives. I stumbled on this after 2+ hours of Google searching. It finally makes sense.

Comment: this was my issue too, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

According to this: http://codeinreview.com/136/enabling-drag-and-drop-over-a-grid-in-wpf/
(Which I am happy to report works!)

All you need to do is add a background on the control that has to get the drop. This will enable hit testing and thus make the drop-feature work.

Note: The background can be transparent, you just have to set it.

Comment: Of course, the reported problem occurs having a background (i.e. it was not a fancy backgroundless UI trying to reach a transparency effect).